# Sample multinomial distribution in Matlab without using mnrnd

Tags: matlab

I know for a random variable x that P(x=i) for each i=1,2,...,100. Then how may I sample x by a multinomial distribution, based on the given P(x=i) in Matlab?

I am allowed to use the Matlab built-in commands `rand` and `randi`, but not `mnrnd`.

Comment: Isn't figuring this out part of your assignment? Otherwise you'd be allowed to use whatever you need. Isn't that right?

Comment: Hint: what does a cumulative distribution function do?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, this is the last part, for a CS class. I am ok at coding but bad at probability...

Comment: @MatthewGunn My impression is to do the following: sample x by rand(0,1) and find i so that p1+p2+..+pi<x<p1+p2+..+pi+p(i+1), then my sample would be just i...

Comment: You might want to take a look at `cumsum`, then.

Comment: `cumsum(p)` is basically giving you the cumulative distribution function (CDF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can sample numbers from any 1 dimensional probability distribution X using a uniform random number generator and the inverse cumulative distribution function of X. This is known as [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

`random_x = xcdf_inverse(rand())`

How does this apply here? If you have your vector `p` of probabilities defining your multinomial distribution, `F = cumsum(p)` gives you a vector that defines the CDF. You can then generate a uniform random number on [0,1] using `temp = rand()` and then find the first row in `F` greater than `temp`. This is basically using the inverse CDF of the multinomial distribution.

Be aware though that for some distributions (eg. gamma distribution), this turns out to be an inefficient way to generate random draws because evaluating the inverse CDF is so slow (if the CDF cannot expressed analytically, slower numerical methods must be used).